# How should I drive my LED panel of 200 diodes?

Tags: led, current, circuit-design, parallel, series

## How should I drive my LED panel of 200 diodes?

### Context

I'm making a board of ultraviolet diodes that will project light onto a photosensitive copper-clad board and etch a design on it with an LCD with all components removed and the UV board acting as a backlight.

This circuit will have 200 UV diodes and I have a few questions.

---

### Diode specification

- Power: 3 W
- Color: Purple Ultra Violet
- Forward current: 600-700 mA
- Forward voltage: DC 3.2-3.6 V
- Quantity: 200
- Link: [Right here!](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/2251832761070682.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.5.21ef1802WxuRph&gatewayAdapt=glo2usa&_randl_shipto=US)

---

### What I know

Right now I know I will need either a lot of power or current, also I know it will be very hot and I need to get that sorted.

#### What I need to know

What I want to know is how should I wire it? Should it be in parallel? Series? How many resistors do I need? If possible, can you show me a small example circuit with like 10 diodes?

How much power should I be sending to the circuit and how much current?

Comment: Unrelated to driving the LEDs, but make sure you put some kind of diffuser layer between the LEDs and whatever they're illuminating to ensure that there's an even brightness across the entire board and you don't have "hot spots" of UV directly beneath each LED.

Comment: I'd probably put 20 or so in series and then build parallel strings of 20 diodes. Drive the whole thing constant current and with a peak current less than 600 mA (per diode) since they look sketchy. More would be fine in series, but you might be worried about high voltage on a diy array.

Comment: @user1850479 I think you would need a separate 600mA constant current source for each string of LEDs, so that would be 10 drivers.

Comment: @PeterJennings I would use a single driver. No good reason to use 10 individual smaller ones.

Comment: @user1850479 Maybe, but how are you going to ensure an even distribution of current across all strings? Surely this assumes the forward voltage drop of each string is almost the same. I agree that the *probable* voltage spread of the sum of N diodes is statistically less that the individual spread of the diodes. The standard deviation of N diodes' drops taken together  is 1/SQRT(N) times that of  N single diodes' drops taken individually.

Comment: @PeterJennings The distribution of current doesn't need to be exactly even, it just needs to be even enough that the brightest string has a safe amount of current.  As long as you are driving the array well below its absolute maximum, that will happen even if the per string variation is large (which isn't too likely anyway as you point out).

Comment: @user1850479 I'm inclined to agree. With a constant current supply it should be OK. As they say, "suck it and see"

Comment: What is the transmission of the light thru your LCD panel? You might find it's not transparent in the UV. You might also find that there is a poor contrast ratio between an on and off pixel. Also, because your source doesn't appear to come from a single point but is diffuse it is important that the masking part of your stack up is as close as possible to the photosensitive layer to avoid light leaking under your mask.

Answer (score 4):

Most commercial applications put as many LEDs in series as possible. How many depends on what power supply you have available. If, for example you have a 24V power supply the maximum would be 6 LEDs in series. With a 48V supply this rises to 13 and a 100V supply can probably drive 27. The number of LEDs in series is simply the supply voltage divided by the forward voltage (worst case 3.6V) rounded down to the nearest integer.
However you need to consider current limiting. Ideally LEDs should be driven from a constant current source or, at the very least, via a current limiting resistor.  So this will have its own voltage drop. For the sake of argument let us assume a 24V supply. If you break your display down into 40 strings of 5 LEDs at 600mA the diodes will drop 18V (5 X 3.6V) leaving 6V to drop across a 10 ohm resistor which will be dissipating 3.6W in it's own right, so use a 5W component. Alternatively you could use 33 strings of 6 LEDs each with a 4.2 ohm 2W resistor but you'd have 2 LEDs left over to drive separately, somehow.
40 strings at 600mA is 24A (or 20.4A if you go the 6 LED route) so that requires a 600W 24V  power supply. Typically like one of these https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256802875151661.html
Many other sources of power supplies are available this is just an example.
I've assumed a 24V supply in my example, but I see that this particular supplier offers a 72V module. You could probably get away with 10 strings of 20 LEDs since 3.6V is the worst case diode drop but you'd have to experiment with the best current limiting resistor. The total power requirement would be a little less (say 500W), and the current would be about 6A. The downside is that 72V can give you a nasty shock whilst 24V isn't too bad under most circumstances.

200 LEDs at 600mA is 120W is a lot of heat to dissipate plus the resistors. You don't say how big your lamp display is but I think you are going to need a substantial heat sink.

Addendum
As one of the comments effectively says, the fewer strings of more LEDs in series the better, but the higher the voltage you will need. Supplies such as this one https://www.aliexpress.us/item/2255800580591859.html are available, but unless you know exactly what you are doing with high voltages (and some of these ones are potentially lethal if misused) don't do it.